# Where should I put local JSON file in React project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, react-redux, directory

I have created one JSON configuration file in react project. Following is the project structure where I kept **userProvisions.json** file ->

```
.
└── /config
└── /public
└── /src
    └── /utils
        ├── userProvisions.json
```

**Question:** Is it a good practice to keep configuration file (**userProvisions.json**) in **src** folder ?

Comment: For me, it depends on how you are going to use it. If it is an application configuration json, from my point of view it should be outside the src, but if it is a component configuration json, it makes sense to me that it is inside that folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It all depends on the purpose of the file, if it is a simple file and you don't have any problem with anyone accessing that file, you can store it where-ever you want, however, on the other hand if it contains crucial data, you can't prevent others from seeing that file. You should use a database to store and process that data.

Seeing your folder structure it is a good idea to store the "JSON
configuration file" in ./config/... -> it's totally up to you.